# gem mongoid : Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mongoid

I'm trying for 2 days now to setup Mongodb with Rails 4.
I've got the following gems in my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'mongo_mapper'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

When I try `bundle install` on my osx shell, I have the following lines :

```
Updating git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
```

I've tried with several versions of mongoid gem but nothing makes the `rails generate mongoid:config` command work.

Any clue ?

**EDIT**

Here is the bundle install --verbose trace

```
Updating git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git
Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
/Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:283:in `rescue in fetch_path'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:258:in `fetch_path'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:454:in `fetch_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:468:in `block in fetch_all_remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_list.rb:90:in `block in each'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_list.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_list.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:466:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:262:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:116:in `specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `block in remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `each'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:163:in `fetch_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:67:in `specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `block in index'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Bundler::HTTPError: Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:268:in `rescue in fetch_all_remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:261:in `fetch_all_remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:116:in `specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `block in remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `each'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:228:in `remote_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:163:in `fetch_specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:67:in `specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `block in index'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Running `bundle update` gives me :

```
Using mongoid (4.0.0.beta1) from git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git (at master) 
Gem::FilePermissionError: You don't have write permissions for the /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin directory.
An error occurred while installing mongoid (4.0.0.beta1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mongoid -v '4.0.0.beta1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Try `bundle install --verbose` and post the result. It's likely internet connection problem or so.

Comment: Ok, I edited my post. I just tried with a wifi connection.
 Now I have an error when running bundle update

Comment: Oh, now I get it with your last comment..! I forgot the "sudo" that solved my problem. Thanks !

Comment: You shall not install gems with sudo. Learn about RVM or RBenv.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced that problem before. In my case i just removed the **s** from the `https` of that line: 
`source 'http://rubygems.org'` 
and adding the following line in the gemfile:

```
source 'http://gems.github.com'
```

It solves my problem. I don't know why. But fortunately it works. :D

Answer (score 0):

It can be temporary network issue as well.
Try restarting network services using command .
`service network restart`
If its *nix machine.